# how can i link -ldl from Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, compilation

I am trying to build the amanda program on ubuntu.
I'm faced with the following error from makefile:

```
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libamserver.la" && ln -s "../libamserver.la" "libamserver.la" )
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wparentheses -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wold-style-definition -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DAMANDA_FILE=\"`basename amindexd.o`\" -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing     -o amindexd amindexd.o disk_history.o list_dir.o ../common-src/libamanda.la libamserver.la ../device-src/libamdevice.la ../common-src/libamanda.la ../amandad-src/libamandad.la -lm -Wl,--export-dynamic -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lnsl -lresolv
libtool: link: gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wparentheses -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wold-style-definition -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DAMANDA_FILE=\"amindexd.o\" -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -o .libs/amindexd amindexd.o disk_history.o list_dir.o -Wl,--export-dynamic -pthread -pthread  ./.libs/libamserver.so /src/amanda-3.3.1/device-src/.libs/libamdevice.so ../device-src/.libs/libamdevice.so /src/amanda-3.3.1/xfer-src/.libs/libamxfer.so /src/amanda-3.3.1/ndmp-src/.libs/libndmlib.so ../common-src/.libs/libamanda.so ../amandad-src/.libs/libamandad.so /src/amanda-3.3.1/common-src/.libs/libamanda.so -lm -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lnsl -lresolv -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib/amanda
/usr/bin/ld: /src/amanda-3.3.1/device-src/.libs/libamdevice.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/bin/ld: /src/amanda-3.3.1/device-src/.libs/libamdevice.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/bin/ld: /src/amanda-3.3.1/device-src/.libs/libamdevice.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From the error message it seems that libtool is not able to link to ldl.
So I manually added "-ldl" to the provided Makefile.

```
LIBS = -lm -Wl,--export-dynamic -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lnsl -lresolv -ldl
```

However, Makefile keeps making the exact same error whenever I try to build.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your complete Makefile and the output of the failing build after you added `-ldl`.

Comment: i'm afraid they are way too long to paste them in the post..

Comment: After you made that change, look at the link line that make prints.  Does the `-ldl` appear there?

Comment: This software is probably configured with `configure`, which might have failed detection of `dlopen`. Check `config.log` for line `checking for dlopen in -ldl` and what is has logged afterwards. Chances are that there is a failed check for linking `-ldl` for any reason.

Comment: just solved by setting LIBS=-ldl before running configure. thanks